# Cocoa-Touch – Delegate confusion

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, delegates, automatic-ref-counting, uiapplicationdelegate

I just started a new project running Xcode 4.2.1 and iOS5 SDK. The project is setup with ARC. I'm trying to set the AppDelegate to be the delegate for UITabBarController by doing `[tabBarController setDelegate:self];` if I do that I get a warning message saying:

```
warning: Semantic Issue: Sending 'AppDelegate *const __strong' to parameter of incompatible type 'id<UITabBarControllerDelegate>'
```

Alright fair enough, I set my AppDelegate to conform to the UITabBarControllerDelegate by doing

```
@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate, UITabBarControllerDelegate>
```

Great, the warning goes away.

I now get another error. In a view controller I want to get a hold of the AppDelegate so I do this: `AppDelegate *appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];` but this will render a warning saying:

```
warning: Semantic Issue: Initializing 'AppDelegate *__strong' with an expression of incompatible type 'id<UIApplicationDelegate>'
```

But if I remove that my AppDelegate conforms to the UITabControllerDelegate protocol my second warning disappears.

Very strange behaviour, what gives Cocoa experts?

Answer (score 81, accepted):

Try doing a typecast before assign the AppDelegate variable.

```
AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
```

And , keep the `UITabControllerDelegate`.

Comment: Hi @Aadhira, This solved my error, but I'm not sure I understand why the solution works. Would you or anyone mind explaining to me? Thank you!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14977284/in-objective-c-why-is-casting-needed-when-assigning-to-a-variable-whose-type-is 

Please refer the above link - @narner