# In Objective-C, why is casting needed when assigning to a variable whose type is specified?

Tags: objective-c

This use of type casting comes up a lot, e.g. in a button tap action:

```
UIButton *button = (UIButton *)sender;
```

My question is why the explicit cast "(UIButton *)" is necessary. Doesn't assigning the value of "sender" to variable "button" already effectively cast it as a pointer to UIButton?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Stephen said, it is not really required.

But it is a quesiton of style and good business practice.

BTW, when you omit it, you get a warning, not an error. 
Just for getting rid of the warning you could simply do:

```
someObject = (id) anotherObject;
```

That will work with references to any Object of any class. You see that there is hardly any casting acutally done. 
You can allways assign to superclasses without cast:

```
objectOfAClass = objectOfSubclassOfA;
```

Bottom line is, it helps you avoiding mistakes by forcing you to think a very brief moment about what you are actually doing there.

Comment: All great answers so far, but I'm choosing this one because of the detail about the compiler warnings. And just to reiterate: assigning to a superclass (without casting) generates **no** warning; assigning to a subclass (without casting) **does** generate a warning. e.g. `UILabel *label; UIView *view = label;` (no warning); `UIView *view; UILabel *label = view;` (warning).

Answer (score 5):

It tells the compiler that you know what you're doing: "I know `sender` *technically* isn't a `UIButon*` but I promise that it always will be at run-time."

Answer (score 2):

In objective-c it is common to write action methods like

```
- (void)didAction:(id)sender
```

This method can be called by any object(eg. UIButton, UIControl etc.), and expected set the sender self.

Ever object is an id. So in that method you have a variable in type of id. If you are sure it is a button then you can cast to UIButton.

Another way is, if you are sure that the method will be called only by a UIButton instance then you can change your action method to

```
- (void)didAction:(UIButton *)senderButton
```

If you do it so, you do not need to cast.

Please note that, for that kind castings you are responsible, that nothing goes wrong. If you unsure you can always check the class of object with

```
- (BOOL)isKindOfClass:(Class)aClass
```

method.